# Hide divs is not working in my browser but works fine in js_fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I only wanted to hide Some div when the page is refreshed.
This works fine in Js_fiddle ([js_fiddle_link](https://jsfiddle.net/imran16/vapahm1p/)),However when i try it in my browser,after hiding all the div it reappears again. what could be the reason ?
Snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.show").hide("2000")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is the testing for different div selection </h1>

<div class="list-group">

  <li>Click here for A</li>
  <li>Click here for B</li>
  <li>Click here for C</li>

</div>

<div class="show">

  This class holds the information aboout the A classs so those who want to join me within this group blah blah blah
</div>
<hr>
<div class="show">
  This class holds the information aboout the B classs so those who want to join me within this group blah blah blah
</div>
<hr>
<div class="show">
  This class holds the information aboout the C classs so those who want to join me within this group blah blah blah
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Job #1 when debugging JS: check the console for errors.

Comment: I did , there's no error

Comment: Well your code works in the fiddle and the snippet, so there must be some inconsistency in your code somewhere. Without seeing an error or a recreation of the issue, no one can help you

Comment: Is the HTML posted in the snippet exactly as per your project code?

Comment: You want this to be shown on pager load, then hide if a user refreshes/reloads the page. Is that right?

Comment: Code works fine when i remove my bootstrap.css link from the header.

Comment: Then this is likely a conflict between an `!important` rule for the `.show` class used by bootstrap and the inline style introduced by your script. Try changing `.show` to another classname and then add in Bootstrap again.

Comment: Indeed Bootstrap 3.3 provides a `.show` helper class with the following rule:
`.show {
  display: block !important;
}`
Always check the Styles applied in your Chrome inspector if the issue is display related.

Comment: Yeah,,that was it ! thank you @SebCooper

Comment: Great, I posted details as an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for conflicts with the `.show` class. As per comments the cause was Bootstrap 3's `.show` helper class with a `display: block !important;` rule overriding the inline styles added by the script.

Changing the `.show` class to another name fixed it.